# Oracle PL/SQL and DocuSign Authorization Code Grant - get 400 Bad Request

Tags: oracle, plsql, docusignapi

I am trying to perform DocuSign Authorization Code Grant via Oracle PL/SQL but I get a 400 Bad Request. It works when I run it via POSTMAN. The headers are correct (For example, I verfified that the authorization code is converted to 64 base correctly. but the POST results I get only 400 Bad request with no reason.

The PL/SQL code is as follows:

```
FUNCTION obtain_access_token (
     p_auth_code in varchar2,
     p_integration_key in varchar2,
     p_secret_key in varchar2,
     p_header1 out varchar2,
     p_header2  out varchar2,
     p_obtain_auth_token out varchar2
    ) RETURN CLOB as
        l_authorization  VARCHAR2(4000);
        l_auth_code varchar2(4000);
        l_resp clob;
        l_wallet_path varchar2(1000):='file:D:\oracle19c\owm\wallets\oracle\wallet';
        l_wallet_pwd varchar2(100) := '*******';
        l_keys varchar2(4000);
        l_encode64_keys varchar2(32767);
    l_body clob           := 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=#AUTH_CODE#';
    l_url  varchar2(100)  := 'https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token';
    l_json apex_json.t_values;
    BEGIN   
      l_keys := p_integration_key ||':'||p_secret_key;
      l_encode64_keys := DOCUSIGN_PkG.convert_to_base64 (p_key=>l_keys);
      l_authorization := rtrim('Basic ' ||  l_encode64_keys);
--
--   Set headers : 
--       Authorization
--       Content-type
--
     apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).name := 'Authorization';  
     apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).value := l_authorization ;
     apex_web_service.g_request_headers(2).name := 'Content-Type';
     apex_web_service.g_request_headers(2).value := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    
     p_header1 := '{'|| 'Authorization'||','||l_authorization||'}';
     p_header2 := '{'|| 'Content-Type'||','||'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'||'}';
--
--   Authorization code
-- 
     l_auth_code := p_auth_code;
-- remove &code=
     l_auth_code := substr(l_auth_code,7);
     l_body := rtrim('grant_type=authorization_code&code=' ||rtrim(l_auth_code))
     --
     -- Issue POST
     --
     l_resp := apex_web_service.make_rest_request (
      p_url         => l_url,
      p_http_method => 'POST',
      p_body        => l_body,
      p_wallet_path => l_wallet_path,
      p_wallet_pwd => l_wallet_pwd
    );
     p_obtain_auth_token:= l_body;
    return l_resp;
    END obtain_access_token;
```

Comment: A few thoughts: (1) are you absolutely sure that `p_auth_code` always includes the `&code=` prefix?  (2) does this code need to be URL-encoded?  (3) does the request body need a `redirect_uri` parameter?  (I ask this as I've recently worked on code doing an OAuth2 auth-code grant and I needed to include that parameter in the request body.)  (4) if you've included your secret key in your question, I strongly recommend getting a new secret key.

Comment: I absolutely know the p_auth_code includes the &code= prefix. I'll look into URL-encoding the auth_code. I don't believe I need the redirect_url based on my conversation with a DocuSign technical staff. I will change the secret key thank you.

Comment: I URL-encoded the code and it did not fix the issue.

Comment: The issue has been fixed.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Would it be possible to share what fixed the problem for you, for the benefit of anyone else who might have the same problem?